# Using CNAME record as MX record (kind of)

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, dns-zone

I'm using the mailgun service and it asks me to setup mxa.mailgun.org and mxb.mailgun.org on my domain, which is fine but I want to use something different on a secondary domain to mask that it's using mailgun.

Is this scenario possible?:

maindomain.com has the following:

```
CNAME - mx1.maindomain.com - mxa.mailgun.org 
CNAME - mx2.maindomain.com - mxb.mailgun.org
```

secondarydomain.com has the following:

```
MX - mx1.maindomain.com
MX - mx2.maindomain.com
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? At least leave a reason

Comment: Downvotes without comment can be assumed to be for one of the reasons listed in the downvote arrow hover text.

Answer (score 2):

No, an MX entry must point to an A or AAAA record.

Comment: Is there are way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: No, not in a reliable way, and it's useless anyway because in the end, the systems will talk to mailgun.org when everything has been resolved. Why would you want to mask that anyway?

Comment: Because in a SaaS product I'm working on I want to give our mx records to our users, not mailguns.

Comment: @Karl It is highly unlikely that your customers will care in the least that you're using mailgun. If they *do* care, they'll be savvy enough to know that you're using them even if you don't present a mailgun MX name directly to them.

Comment: Sure, if someone wants to find out, they can. But some customers will most likely care imo, so I'd rather hide it and let people dig if they want to dig

Comment: If they care, you don't want them as a customer. If they think you can provide better mail services on your own than mailgun can, they're going to be a *very* demanding customer.

Comment: It will lock Karl in to Mailgun though. If he ever wants to move, or Mailgun goes bust, then all his customers have to change their MX records. We're facing this problem too and it worries me to no end. Any ideas here? :/